# Discord.py Emoji 400

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot with Discord.py and I keep getting an error when trying to react to an embed I sent, I posted the whole loop below, but mainly the error points to the line `await msg.add_reaction(emoji=reactions)`.  I know that the the unicode string has to be passed in the function above, but it seems like it would not take it if it was received via the text channel even though the unicode was exactly the same.  I even added the print function to just see if the unicode printed exactly the same and it did which the same exact length, no spaces.  If I just input the unicode directly as a string for example: `await msg.add_reaction(emoji='\U0001f310')` then it works and is able to react to that message with the correct reaction, but if I have it received via msg.content and then passed to the function then it throws the unkown emoji error.  I know that the message content is good since it gets printed exactly to the console.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the error I get:

`\U0001f310
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 227, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\voicebot discord\test2.py", line 94, in on_message
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji=reactions)
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\message.py", line 708, in add_reaction
    await self._state.http.add_reaction(self.id, self.channel.id, emoji)
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 214, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400): Unknown Emoji`

My Code:

```
while embedLoop:

        await channel.send('What is the title?')
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        title = msg.content            
        await channel.send('The title is ' + title)

        await channel.send('What is the description?')
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        desc = msg.content
        await channel.send('The description is ' + desc)



        await channel.send('Enter emoji unicode: ')
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        reactions = msg.content



        embed=discord.Embed(colour = 4691711)
        embed.add_field(name=title, value= desc, inline=False)
        msg = await embedChannel.send(embed=embed)
        print(reactions)

        await msg.add_reaction(emoji=reactions)
```

Comment: Just a long shot but did you try ```msg.add_reaction(emoji=unicode(reactions))```?

Comment: @accdias I get a `NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined` error.   It should just be able to take the string verbatim.  Not sure what's going on as I have researched this heavily.

Comment: How are you defining `reactions`?  It looks like you may be trying to send an escaped version of the emoji `'\\U0001f310'`.  Try `await msg.add_reaction(emoji="\N{GLOBE WITH MERIDIANS}")`